# d3. Missing data. Only plotting the initial value in each group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm building upon the very nice d3 example produced here http://2011.12devsofxmas.co.uk/2012/01/data-visualisation/

and I'm still in the exploratory phase, figuring out what all the bits of code in the original version do, and how to adapt it to accomplish my visualization goals.

Here is a block of the current version. Visualization is best viewed by clicking "Open in a new window"

http://bl.ocks.org/natemiller/119c49ffc4f159fd49ce

Being relatively new to d3 and very new to JavaScript, its been a rather steep learning curve for sure. In any case, the issue I have run into with my small, simple practice example, is that not all the data is being plotted. Instead of 7 data points, you can see I only have 3. I'm not entirely sure what is going on here.

Some background troubleshooting I've done: The original code used a d3/d3.js script from version 2.7 rather than what I am using here ("http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"). Additionally, they used another script d3/d3.csv.js, I assume to read in the .csv file. I have omitted this script and just used d3.csv() within d3.js.

If I leave both of these original scripts in the code, my visualization plots properly (7 data points), but if I replace the original d3.js (v.2.7) with the current version I get the plot with only three data points.

Any idea what is going on here? Thoughts on how I can modify the code I have posted so that all the datapoints are plotted?

Thanks for you help,

Nate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 55, where you have `.data(rawData, function (d) { return d.site;}),`

try changing to `.data(rawData),`

The second argument in .data is a key. When you try to create your circle svg elements, it's looking at the key, which only has three distinct values (site 1, site 2, and site 3 in d.site), and hence only creates three circles.

Reference on the data selection method is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data/)

Comment: Perfect! Of course, that makes sense, but I hadn't recognized that as a key. Thanks so much!